# Why use SpringJpa paging query to report SQL syntax errors?

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G6G4.png)

When I used SpringJpa to implement paged queries I got a syntax error but I don't know what it was, if you put quotes around it you can't query the data.

Comment: Please post code, images are not entertained here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change `like %?%` to `like %?1%`

or `like CONCAT('%',?,'%')`